# Facebook / Google / Twitter remembering login

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

Following the steps detailed [in this azure tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-dotnet/) to introduce authentication via facebook, twitter or google works, but as the page notes this requires the user to log in every time the application starts. This isn't really ideal.

The Azure site details how to introduce a single sign on experience through the Live SDK. Does anyone know how to do this using the alternative providers (e.g. Facebook) ? Is there a mobile services specific way of doing it?

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with this specific platform, but in general 3rd party login is usualy used for one-time login (or for restoring that login)

I mean:
1) Login with 3rd party
2) Automaticaly create your own user based on data received from 3rd party, also store that 3rd party user ID
3) Save cookie/on-device identeficator for your user
4) Following logins are made based on cookie/on-device identificator
If it is lost for some reason user relogins with 3rd party and you compare received 3rd party ID to stored in your DB

Comment: Actually yes, that sounds correct. Now I need to figure out where I am supposed to store the on device identifier within win8 apps.

Answer (score 0):

Josh Twist has a couple posts that you'll probably find helpful.

Here, he walks through generating an auth token: http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Generating_your_own_ZUMO_auth_token_Day_8_.aspx

In this entry, he covers setting the auth token in Mobile Services and caching a user's identity: http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Setting_the_auth_token_in_the_Mobile_Services_client_and_caching_the_user_rsquo_s_identity_Day_10_.aspx

In this post, he follows up with how to handle expired tokens: http://thejoyofcode.com/Handling_expired_tokens_in_your_application_Day_11_.aspx

Between those three posts you should  be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

The support for single sign-on for providers remembering the login was recently added to the Azure Mobile Service. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/02/05/enabling-single-sign-on-for-windows-8-azure-mobile-apps.aspx explains how to use that feature.